# SGE - can't get password entry for user "jenkins"

Tags: jenkins, sungridengine

I'm running the following SGE command thru Jenkins without any problem:

```
qsub -N my_job_name -q my_queue -l hostname=my_hostname -w e -notify -m n -cwd -b y -o /dev/null -e my_error_path -v my_env_var ...
Your job 1082782 ("my_job_name") has been submitted
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I'm running a tool/script thru Jenkins that calls the previous SGE command and I get the following issue:

```
Q: Submitting my_job_name to SGE queue my_queue
S: my_job_name not compared:
SGE job exited
Job ID was 1082783
---------- Full accounting info from SGE ----------
SGE job entered error state: 1082783
TextTest terminated this job as a result. SGE's error reason follows:
error reason 1: can't get password entry for user "jenkins". Either the user does not exist or NIS error!
Results:
Tests that did not succeed:
my_job_name not compared: SGE job exited
Tests Run: 1, Incomplete: 1
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: I suspect your script is running on different node/user account.  Try to print "env" and debug that part.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I was having this problem this week. Turned out the updated httpd won't allow user account/password info to propagate to the compute nodes. This links provide a solution https://unix.bris.ac.uk/2017/08/01/rocks-clusters-the-httpd-update-that-breaks-your-cluster-and-how-to-fix-it/